# VW Polo 1.4 MPI 2001 won't start up

Tags: starting, vw, cranks-wont-run, polo

So car was doing great, nothing suspicious, then next day it won't start up. It cranks, I can hear fuel pump, there is no lights on dash board(except battery light wich always turns on when starting up engine, it usually stays for cuople seconds and then turns off), also, I can feel fuel pump relay "click" when I turn key so I don't think there is a problem with it.
Also, car starts up sometimes and then immediatly turns off.

Anyone has any idea of what it could be?

Edit: fuel pump sounds like it's struggling(it didn't sounded like that before). Maybe low battery?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!